# ASP.NET: Saving Static Member in Database with Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I save a static member in database using Code First?

For instance:

```
 public class Department
    {
        /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        public static int TotalLevelNumber;

        public int Id { get; set; } 

        /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        public int Level { get; set; }

        /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        public Department ParentDepartment { get; set; }

        /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        public List< Department> SonDepartment { get; set; }
    }
```

`TotalLevelNumber` is a static member which stands for total level number. When`TotalLevelNumber`=4, All the `Department` instance can only have property `Level` from 1-4. I'd like to save `TotalLevelNumber` into database. How to do that? The situation now is that Code First will not generate anything regarding `TotalLevelNumber`

Comment: When does it change? If it's the same for every object why does it need to be saved with them?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It changes when administrator increase or decrease it through GUI.

Comment: What happens then? All objects in database should change? It's clearly not property of Department so it should not be stored there

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No instance will change after  `TotalLevelNumber` change. It's not a property of a `Department` instance, but a property of `Department` class, IMO. Where do you suggest me to save `TotalLevelNumber`?

Comment: Save TotalLevelNumber in a different static class and then set it on class initialization